# The uniqueness of big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Is big O notation unique? Apparently, by the defintion of big O notation

```
f(x) = O(n(x)) if limsup(x->inf) |f(x)|/n(x) = 1
```

Given `f(x) = O(n(x))` we also have `f(x)=O(n(x)+1)`, such `n(x)+1` satisfies the definition, too.

The problem is, does there exist a set of all `n(x)` such that for **any** `f(x)` there **exists and exists only one** `n(x)` in the set such that `f(x)=O(n(x))`?

For example, `S = {n | n(x) = x^a log(x)^b, (a,b) are both integers}`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, for any growth order O(f(n)) there exists an infinity of variants, such as O(f(n)+g(n)) where g(n)=o(f(n)). Presumably, these form equivalence classes and you can choose a "canonical" member from each to ensure uniqueness.

In any case, the number of classes is uncountably infinite, just for the fact that O(n^α) exist for all real α, and I don't see how in practice you could specify these canonical members.

The question is slightly different if you consider the order of growth of the running times of algorithms rather than general functions, and/or the order functions having a closed-from expression, as the algorithms and the formulas are countable.

---

**Quiz:**

What is the canonical representation of the order of growth of f(n) if f(n)^f(n²)=n ?

Comment: This is more close to my original question. More specifically: "Is it possible to contruct such set?" Just the fact that you can choose a canonical member ideally... Is it possible to contruct it? (For example, given the axiom in ZFC.)

Comment: @Acc-lab: closed form or not ?

Comment: Quiz answer: O(log(n)/n)

Comment: @AdFortia: this makes f(n)^f(n²) tend to1, does not it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust does it tend to zero because n growths faster than log(n)?

Comment: @AdFortia: indeed.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Closed form then. It'll be really tricky otherwise I guess?

Comment: @Acc-lab: you can take the first formula in some collation order, for every class.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "first formula"?

Comment: @Acc-lab: didn't we say closed-form ? You can sort them.

Comment: Got it. "every class" means different functions...?

Comment: @Acc-lab: every class of order. E.g. O(n²), O(n³)

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior not the exact match. When you write that `n(x)` and `n(x)+1` satisfy the definition, your are providing an example which indirectly answer to your question: there is more than one `n(x)` in the set `S` such that `f(x)=O(n(x))`. Bio O notation is unique not in the sense that we have to find a unique n(x) that satisfy the definition but in the sense that we have to find the class of function that have the same growth rate. When we say O(x) with `n(x)=x` we are choosing `x` as a representative of the entire class of linear function. Sure we can say O(x+1) but it will be redundant because, as I said, we are referring to a class and not a specific function.

Comment: My problem is not what is big O notation for, but does there exist a set for all the possible big O notation function.

Comment: Sure it exists and it is generated by the definition of Big O notation. If you are searching for a "parameterized" function, for example ```ax+b where (a,b) are both integers``` for linear function, I guess this is not possible because ```x^2/x``` has the same asymptotic behavior of ```x``` and cannot be derived from ```ax+b```.

Comment: The set can be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Exactly, this is why in the definition we have a generic ```n(x)```. In fact we cannot rappresent it as a parametric function.

Comment: I doubt there could be a countable family. I suspect you could make this into a proof: suppose f[n] n = 1.. is such a family, Then let F[n](x) = max(i<=n, f[n](x)) and F[n]<=F[n+1]. Let G(x) = n*F[n](x) if x in [n,n+1]. Then G() can't be O(f[n]) for any n

Comment: @dmuir: n^α is uncountable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed, but the OP's example was countable, which made me think they wanted a countable set.

Comment: @dmuir: I was showing you an immediate way to prove that no countable solution is possible.

Comment: @dmuir Indeed I made a countable example. I don't know how do I represent a uncountable set easily, in fact.

Comment: But I was excepting (if such set exists) it will be uncountable.